# How to structure a mixed model when observations represent all pairwise combinations of two nuisance features?

Tags: mixed-model

Suppose a given observation in a dataset has two characteristics among many others: X1 and X2, where X1 and X2 can be from the set of possibilities A, B, C, or D. Thus, for any given observation, we could have:

Group 1: AB, AC, AD

Group 2: BC, BD

Group 3: CD

Suppose further that I in fact obtain 6 measurements, each having a unique X1 X2 combo from the list above. I don't want to use X1 and X2 as fixed effects, because they represent nuisance factors. Now, in a traditional mixed model, each group listed would represent groups of correlated observations. But an observation with a "C" in it shows up in each group, muddling up this structure in my mind (we can say something similar for the other letters). Can I simply throw in a random effect for each letter, or does this structure merit some special modeling approach? Answers welcome--I particularly like citations for further reading. Thank you in advance!

Additional information based on comments:
There is no formal experimental design, so we are not attempting causal inference. Rather, we have a large dataset which we know has the correlation structure mentioned above, and we are simply trying to address it by running a GLMM (logistic). Our research questions primarily center around the classic questions: 1) can we predict some response variable and 2) can we conduct inference for these predictions. Unfortunately, I cannot give more details on the variables, but let's just treat this example in the abstract. Apologies in advance.

Comment: Please can you explain the study design and what these variables represent in real life, and also let us know what your research question(s) is/are.

Comment: Robert, thanks for your comment. Attempted clarifications above. Would it be helpful if I generated a synthetic toy dataset?

Comment: Yes, a synthetic dataset would be good. You said you aren't doing causal inference, but then you say you want to " conduct inference for these predictions". What exactl;y is your research question ? What is the relation between the characteristics X1 and X2, and what do  A, B, C, and D represent, and what are you trying to predict ? It's rather difficult to do applied statistics with abstract information !

Comment: Okay, I'll get  to work on that. And I'll try to make the example real by making an analogous scenario. Thanks! And would you agree that in experimental design we can talk about causal inference...vs just regular inference from a generic regression with no design where we are getting measures of variability/confidence and talking about relationships without and inkling of the direction of causation...probably just semantics.

Comment: Perhaps just semantics, and open to interpretaion. Sure we can talk about causal inference in an experimental setting - in fact that's the classical settting for causal inference (eg clinical trials). .. "*regular inference from a generic regression with no design*" - that could be causal inference in observational studies (eg Pearl, Greenland, Hernan etc) . It does get tricky when we talk about inference, but not *causal inference".  Sure, we can do that. We can talk about "associations" rather than "effects", but it is very common for people to make causal claims.

Comment: I agree with all of the above.